# How to get the number of weeks from given year

Tags: ios, calendar

I have successfully retrieved a week number from a date, but now I want to get how many weeks are in a given year.

How do I do that?

Comment: I am pretty sure in every year there is 52 weeks, if you know what i mean :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the number of Weeks using `NSCalendar` and `NSDateComponents`

```
- (NSInteger) getNumberOfWeeks : (NSDate *) fromDate {
    NSCalendar *cal = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *components = [cal components:NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear fromDate:fromDate];
    return [components weekOfYear];
}
```

This method will return number of week from December 31 to the date which you pass in this function.

Comment: thanks, exactly what i want, but what if i want to is get whole week numbers of particular year, than which date i should pass?

Comment: I think the new year start from 26th of december, so pass 25th of december in the date.